# Unable to install Tesseract on Ubuntu 14.04 vagrant box

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-14.04, tesseract

I am trying to install Tesseract on Ubuntu(14.04) vagrant box but getting following dependency error. I am not sure what it solution to solve dependency?

**Error message**

`sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-66-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-66-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-66-generic but it is not going to be installed
 tesseract-ocr : Depends: liblept4 but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libtesseract3 (>= 3.03~) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: tesseract-ocr-eng (>= 3.01~) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: tesseract-ocr-osd but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: tesseract-ocr-equ but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```